# JavaFX: ComboBox<Test> get and set item according to ID field of Test

Tags: java, javafx

I have a ComboBox. And this combobox has `items=ObservableList<Test>`. In order to work with object Test I set cell factory for combobox:`combobox.setCellFactory(...)`. Class Test is the following:

```
public class Test{
  private Integer id;
  private String name;
  //+getters and setters
}
```

Questions:

1. How can I make combobox set selected Test with id=X (list of Tests is already added to combobox)?
2. How can I get currently selected Test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `ComboBox<Test> combo` :

1) `combo.getSelectionModel().select( X );` where X is an index of `Test`
2) `combo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();` returns the `Test`

Comment: Thank you. What is the best way for finding the index of Test? Should I iterate over observableList to check if every Test has certain id? Maybe there are some internal methods?

Comment: You simply do `int indexOfTest = comboBox.getItems().indexOf(test);` You also should overwrite `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods in `Test` class if the `id` property represents the identity of an instance.

Comment: @Surprised Coconut By `comboBox.getItems().indexOf(test);` you can find the index of object if you HAVE this object reference. The problem is to get the reference to Test with ID=X

Comment: @iJava2. No you can directly select the Test with combo.getSelectionModel().select( myTest );. But as Surprised Coconut said you need to properly override equals() and hashCode() methods.

Comment: I understand that I can't do select(Test). What for should I override them - In oder to get with select(index)? Or to get reference to Test object from observalist list by ID (not index). I don't understand...

Comment: @iJava2 Sorry actually I meant you **can** select Test object directly. Rephrasing: " you can directly select the Test with combo.getSelectionModel().select( myTest );. But as Surprised Coconut said you need to properly override equals() and hashCode() methods. "

Comment: Ok. That is clear now. However the main problem is how to get reference to Test object with id=X? If I have reference I can do either select(indexOf(test)) or select(test)+override equals and hashCode.

Comment: @iJava2. I mixed up your ID with index :). Surprised Coconut' s answer is a standard way to go. Otherwise create equals() and hashcode() methods based on ID field. (In Netbeans right-click, select "Generate code", select ID field). Then combo.getItems().select(new Test(X)); which will compare Test with ids and select Test with id=X. As you can see it is a hack smelling bad :)

Comment: And I couldn't understand why you are telling me about index :)

Answer (score 1):

Heres the code that selects one `Test` instance by id.

```
public void selectTestById(Integer id){
  for(Test test : comboBox.getItems()){
    if(test.getId().equals(id)){
      comboBox.getSelectionModel().select(test);
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the only way if only the id is given.